# Close all ContextMenu with mouse button

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is there a way to close all opened context menus opened on the scene?

When I press a button I would like to close all Context menus opened by right muse click.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just have some data structure, say a `Stack<ContextMenu>` Where every time you make a context menu, you push it on the stack, and every time you hide it, you pop it off the stack. Then when you press a certain button, just iterate through the stack and call the `.hide()` method of contextMenu, on each item i the stack, hiding them as you go, and voila! that should do it.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean by example with Grid Pane? Any meaningful example would need to be a self-sustained little application, what basic pane you use shouldn't matter. I don't have any any context menu code examples anywhere handy though, sorry.